# To sum Column values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i want to sum the column of `freightCharge` and `LoadingandUnloadingcharges` and add as new collumn `totalcost`  values I have tried the below code and couldn't able to do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo 
     , CASE WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)  
            ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00) END FreightCharge
     , CASE WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00) 
            ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00) END LoadingandUnloadingcharges 
FROM GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND  
LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherExpenseCost OEC ON OEC.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `select distinct` and window functions, when good old-fashioned aggregation will do.  Then, in SQL, you cannot re-use an alias in the same select where it is defined.  However, your logic is simple enough to repeat (the alternative is a subquery or CTE):

```
SELECT GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo,
       (CASE WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1
             THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)  
             ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
        END) FreightCharge,
       (CASE WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1
             THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00) 
             ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
        END) LoadingandUnloadingcharges ,
       (CASE WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1
             THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00) + Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00) 
             ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00) + Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
        END) FreightCharge,
FROM GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND LEFT OUTER JOIN
     GoodsReceivedNote GRN
     ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID = GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     OtherExpenseCost OEC
     ON OEC.GoodsReceivedNoteID = GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID   
GROUP BY GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo;
```

Note:  If the two tables could each have duplicates, then the sums are probably not what you want.  That is, I don't think your original query is reasonable, but that is not the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want Sum of FreightCharge and LoadingandUnloadingcharges:

```
Select SUM(FreightCharge) FreightCharge, SUM(LoadingandUnloadingcharges) LoadingandUnloadingcharges, SUM(FreightCharge) + SUM(LoadingandUnloadingcharges) TotalCost
from
(SELECT DISTINCT GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo ,CASE  
WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1   
THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)  
ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00)  
END FreightCharge,CASE  
WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1   
THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)  
ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)  
END LoadingandUnloadingcharges 
FROM GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND  
LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherExpenseCost OEC ON OEC.GoodsReceivedNoteID=GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID) as sub
```